# Can we integrate Struts 2.0 with Spring 3.0 +

Tags: spring, struts2, struts2-spring-plugin

I am new to Struts . Can we integrate Struts 2.0 with Spring 3.0 +  . I am hearing people say "it is not possible to integrate it". Is this true .

If so is there any tutorial on the web having an example ?

edit :

There is a plugin to integrate Struts 2 and Spring 2  (struts2-spring-plugin-2.0.11.2.jar) . Do we have similar one for Struts 2 and Spring 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well we always can use Spring 3.x with Struts 2.x and Struts2.x has already a plug in in place to accomplish this.

here is the link [Struts2 spring Integration](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.8/docs/spring-plugin.html)

Struts2 use its internal DI for creation of Actions,Results,Interceptor using the plug in will delegate the call of creation of these key objects to Spring DI.
hope this will help you

**edit**

The Strus2 Spring Plug in works well even with Spring 3.x and we are using this in our current application it actually use your Spring jars and you have to place them in the lib.This plug in just overrides Struts2.x Object factory which is responsible for creating struts2 core component.
So just go ahead do some experiment with it and if you face problem in integrating you can always post queries here

Comment: Why we need to integrate Struts and spring? Shall we use Spring Mvc alone? is there any specific reason to integrate spring and struts. Please clarify

Comment: @muthu: that is up to you to decide which one you want to use, i have used both and personally i like struts2 more and MVC so are many people and same time they want to use power of Spring to manage there service layer as well struts2 component creation so there arise need to integrate spring DI with struts2

Answer (score 0):

The Spring 3.0 documentation for Struts 1.x and 2.x is [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/web-integration.html#struts).

It's technically possible to integrate Spring with really just about anything. For example you can use the IoC container from anywhere in your code by constructing a new `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` and passing in a standard context XML resource on the classpath. There's generally not a need to do that though, as it integrates pretty well with most web frameworks. It is however convenient to use for unit tests.